# getting error of cursor while fetching single row from mysqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

hi am facing an error while getting a long string from sqlite. is there any limit to store long string in sqlite.
i am facing  below error

```
 Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

here is my create table query

```
 private static final String CREATE_TABLE2 = "create table " + SHAREDPREFERANCEVIDEO_TABLE + " ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
        "storedvalue1 TEXT)";
```

and here is function of fetching single row which is only one row in my table

```
  public String sharedprefindb (int position) {

    String value="";
    String id =Integer.toString(position);
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  *  FROM "+ " sharedpreferancevideo_talbe " + " WHERE ID = ? ", new String[] {id});;
    if(cursor.getCount()!=0)
    {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                value=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("storedvalue1"));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return value;
}
```

my this code is working fine in another project in which string is very small
but in this code i am storing encrepted data so its text is verylong. 
so any idea where is i am doing wrong.

Comment: the limit is 2147483647 bytes.

Comment: but its storing string problem is while fetching data from table @Adhithya any idea?

Comment: remove double semicolonin `rawQuery()`.

Comment: One suggestion is change `storedvalue1` type from string to blob(byte). At insert time convert string to byte[] and insert then after getting convert back to string

Comment: let me try this suggestion, will inform you @Nitin patel

Comment: after converting TEXT type to BLOB still getting same error. "**Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.**" @nitin patel

Comment: Try demo with changing `db.rawQuery("select * from "+SHAREDPREFERANCEVIDEO_TABLE+"",null);` and what you get.

Comment: not working still same error.

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: still trying. problem with encrypted data. because any other data can stored and retrived easily with same table and query @Nitin Patel

Comment: See my updated answer and try change like line `value=cursor.getString..` in answer.

Comment: If "verylong" means more than 2MB, then you're out of luck and should not be using Android sqlite.

Comment: i already tried to get string value from column index. it not working for this problem. @nitin patel.  problem is with encrypted data encrypted string not even work in Toast. i am using Base64 to encode video file.

Comment: @user7824858 What a man!!! Are you storing video file in sqlite? Better to store in folder, not in sqlite.

Comment: i need to encrypt video file so no one can access it from internal storage. that's why i am encrypting it and storing it in sqlite .  i need to access video from my own app only .i dont want to make video accessible in internal storage.is there any other way to get this function done.?? @nitin patel

Comment: I think `getFilesDir() ` creates app-specific directory and it is hidden from user and deleted with app uninstall. And add `.media` empty hidden file in directory to not show to user(/gallery). I hope this will help you.

Comment: thank buddy @nitin patel. let me try this one

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
Try this solution by changing your function:

```
public String sharedprefindb (int position) {

    String value="";
    String id =String.valueOf(position);
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  *  FROM "+ " sharedpreferancevideo_talbe " + " WHERE ID = '"+position+"'", null);;
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                value=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(1));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return value;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but not working still getting same error. cursor is not empty it return value 1 when i get count of cursor. facing problem while getting value from cursor.

Comment: Then one suggestion is change `storedvalue1` type from string to blob(byte). At insert time convert string to byte[] and insert then after getting convert back to string.